# Is there a way to convert a .py file to a .txt/.pdf file, such that is does not save that txt/pdf file into storage?

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm creating a demo for a chatbot that takes a github repository as an input, such that you can ask it questions about the code in the repo. I was working on the UI and I want the user to be able to view the .py files next to the conversation with the chatbot. I couldn't find a better way other than to convert the code into a text or pdf file and just embed the pdf file on the webpage. But I don't want it to save a new pdf file everytime, so if a user switches the file they want to view, the previous "pdf" gets removed from memory. I am hosting the application using streamlit.

I tried to use pandoc but it gave an error that said it does not accept .py files for conversion but it accepts .ipynb.

Not really a technical issue, just stumped on how to go about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display Python code on a webpage using highlight.js and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335743/display-python-code-on-a-webpage-using-highlight-js-and-jquery)

Comment: no, this shows how to do it in .js, streamlit is a python package for local hosting websites. so the file I'm trying to do the conversion of other files in is also in python

Comment: You can use the "raw" interface on github to show a file as plain text, without the gitgub GUI.  example https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oven-sh/bun/main/src/bun.js/resolve_message.classes.ts

Comment: get the text of the code as described by @JohnGordon, and put it inside a [code](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/text/st.code) block: `import requests; st.code(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oven-sh/bun/main/src/bun.js/resolve_message.classes.ts").text)`

Comment: also any time you have something expecting a file, but you don't want to write to the local storage, you can use `io.BytesIO`. Just write the data into it as if you were writing a normal file, then rewind it with `seek(0)` and pass the buffer to (mostly) anything expecting a file object. Should behave the same, but never gets written to disk.

Comment: oh this might help a lot! currently i download the entire input repo from github and then load them using the local directories. is there a way to view the local files raw or would i have to change how i load the repository entirely? @JohnGordon's suggestion does sound like a better idea in the long run

Comment: @RaghavKaul `io` buffers act as buffers, not file systems. possibly, you can use an in-memory file system, depeinding on what you need, there is one implemented for [PyFilesystem2](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/memoryfs.html) ... you can [see the source for how that was accomplished if you are interested](https://github.com/PyFilesystem/pyfilesystem2/blob/master/fs/memoryfs.py)... you might be able to walk the github repo using the github API and create the repo in memory use PyFileSystem2

Comment: I was being stupid, the simplest answer was right there in front of me. as of now, for the local files, I simply opened the .py using open("file", "r") and used the read() function in place of the body in st.code(body) and it worked! it just never struck me that .py files could be read as text. it was just a frustrated hail mary that I came to do that. Guess my problem's solved for now. Although I will be using your ideas for the final version of the app. Thank You!

Comment: @RaghavKaul Smart! Maybe post it as an answer so other people can learn from it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! There was no need to use file converters to have raw text.
For doing this with local files, simply

```
import streamlit as st
file1 = open("file.py", "r")
st.code(file1.read(), language = "python")
```

will work like a charm. Realistically, you can pass file1.read() wherever it expects raw text.

For pulling files from github, @JohnGordon and @Aaron's method works best.

```
import requests
import streamlit as st
st.code(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oven-sh/bun/main/src/bun.js/resolve_message.classes.ts"),language = "python")
```

This will grab raw text of the file directly from github.